# Override a static constant int in .h file in Objective-C?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, user-interface, view

I'm trying to build an app in OC and have a constant in `.h` file like this that defines how many columns should be on a menu:

```
// cellManager.h
static int const cellNumberPerRow = 4;
```

Now in my view manager file(`.m`), I need to change the number of columns to 3 when the font size changes. So far I have tried:

```
// menuManagerView.m
if ([self isBigFontSize]) {
     // ....
     cellNumberPerRow = 3;
     // ...
```

But this gives me an error `Cannot assign to variable 'cellNumberPerRow' with const-qualified type 'const int'`; And when I tried to add identifier before like this:

```
static int const cellNumberPerRow = 3;
```

There is a warning `Unused variable 'cellNumberPerRow'` and the column number remains 4;

I feel like there should be an elegant way to do this but couldn't find it anywhere. I'm really new to iOS dev so would appreciate anyone's input, Thanks!

## UPDATE

I defined a new integer variable, assigned the value of const variable to it, and replaced all old `cellNumberPerRoe` with the new variable in the `.m` file. Now it worked. But I wonder if there's any better way to do this?

```
static int newCellNumberPerRow = cellNumberPerRow;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change the value of a constant under some circumstances it implies it's no longer a constant. You could circumvent the `const` compiler check by using a pointer, but that's counterproductive. It'd be much easier to just drop `const` from definition altogether.

What I would suggest as an *alternative* is a computed property in your file manager class defined like this:

```
typedef NS_ENUM(int, CellNumberPerRow) {
    defaultCellNumberPerRow = 4,
    smallerCellNumberPerRow = 3,
};

@interface YourManager: NSObject
@property(readonly,nonatomic) int currentCellNumberPerRow;
@end

@implementation DocumentItem
-(int)currentCellNumberPerRow {
     if ([self isBigFontSize]) {
        return smallerCellNumberPerRow;
     }
     return defaultCellNumberPerRow;
}
@end
```

Now to get the appropriate cell number per row you would use `currentCellNumberPerRow` property instead.

Perhaps making the `currentCellNumberPerRow` a class property `@property(class,...)` instead of instance property could also turn out convenient.